# session_write_close equivalent for asp.net (Disable and Enable Sessions programmatically)

Tags: asp.net

I'm looking for a way to turn on and off session in asp.net in code programmatically.

In php this can easily achieved by using: `session_write_close` and then `session_start` function to enable it again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible in .net below 4

On ASP.NET 4.0 you can use this like of code to enable and disable sessions:

```
HttpContext.Current.SetSessionStateBehavior(SessionStateBehavior.Default);

*  Default: passing this means that everything works as before (ie, you control session through the @page directive or the <pages> entry in the web.config file);
* Required: session state is enabled for read/write access;
* ReadOnly: gives access to read only session state;
* Disabled: turns off session state for the current request.
```

Comment: 7 years later, I wonder if anything has changed? It appears not...I still can't find any way to truly emulate php's `session_write_close`.